Ist possible to navigate from a page that has a Router outlet to a completely different one outside of the router outlet in Angular 17?
I am developing a real estate angular app that will allow clients to buy, sell and post properties on the site. So on the tittle bar I created menus which has router links that will navigate to different part of the app. Below the title bar is the main component that contains the router outlet for all the menus on the tittle bar. There's a blog menu item in the tittle bar which I want its page to be stand alone, not included in the  router outlet of the main component. Please how can I achieve that if it's possible?
I read somewhere but I didn't quite understand but it seems like you can have multiple router outlets but I can't get my head around it but I do understand how child route works.

can u make a simple stackblitz example ?

I guess Stack blitz would be best, but along with that I have few questions as mentioned below -

Do you want the new page to open in same tab or some new tab.
If in the same tab you could give a head level route in app.routing.ts basically your head routing and that should solve the issue.

If still not clear, I can definitely have a look at the code and help you on this.

I begin to realize the fact that the only way to navigate pages in angular app is through router outlet.
